# When putting my classes in a package the code breaks

Tags: java

I have some java classes that work fine until I put them in a package (which they really should be in) and I can't work out why.

Class Board

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel {
    public Board() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Class Skeleton

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Skeleton extends JFrame {

    public Skeleton() {
        add(new Board());
        setTitle("Skeleton");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 280);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Skeleton();
    }
}
```

And all this works fine until I put

`package skeleton;`

at the top of each one.

upon doing so I get

```
skeleton.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        add(new Board());
                ^
  symbol:   class Board
  location: class Skeleton
1 error
Error: Could not find or load main class skeleton.Skeleton
```

Its probably something simple that i have overlooked but I can't seem to find out what is wrong with it.

Edit

Both the classes are in a file called skeleton and skeleton is always spelled correctly.

Im am running javac on both Board.java and Skeleton.java and java on skeleton.Skeleton

EDIT 2

I fixed the

```
skeleton.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
            add(new Board());
                    ^
      symbol:   class Board
      location: class Skeleton
```

error, I forgot I was passing each file to javac individually, but the

```
Error: Could not find or load main class skeleton.Skeleton
```

still persists.

Comment: Sorry that this sounds so blow-arsed, but did you spell "skeleton" the same in each of the two java files; and also move them both to a directory called skeleton?

Comment: move classes in package skeleton to folder skeleton

Comment: Aha!  You seem to have skeleton.java, lower-case, for a class called Skeleton.  The filename has to match the class name, including case.  Does this help?

Comment: Actually Skeleton.java has an upper case 'S'.

Comment: Really?  The error message that you pasted in would seem to indicate otherwise.  What's the javac command that you're using to compile it?

Comment: C:>game\skeleton javac @sourcefiles    
java skeleton.Skeleton       sourcefiles is a .txt file containing the names Board.java and Sceleton.java in plain text.

Comment: Uhm... you said "Board.java and Sceleton.java in plain text"... are you really, really sure about your correct spelling of "Sceleton" vs. "Skeleton"... as @David suggested?

Comment: Everything has been spelled correctly.

Comment: Everything including "Sceleton" in your text file...? You seem awfully certain for someone who gets c's and k's mixed up ;-)

Comment: @Allan you need to edit your question to include your build procedure exactly as you are running it. If you need an example see John's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your code in my machine and it works fine.

Named them as Board.java and Skeleton.java

```
~$ cd skeleton
~/skeleton$ ls
Board.java  Skeleton.java
~$ cd ..
~$ javac skeleton/*.java
~$ ls skeleton
Board.class  Board.java  Skeleton.class  Skeleton.java
~$ java skeleton.Skeleton
```

Output came flashing on my screen!!

I tired this way too.

```
~$ cat arglist
skeleton/Board.java
skeleton/Skeleton.java
~$ javac @arglist
~$ java skeleton.Skeleton
```

That too works.

Comment: Thats not so much an answer as it is a statement that were doing something different. It doesn't really help.

Comment: If @John's answer (+1 from me) proves that it should work in principle, then it's an indication that you have some minor problem in the way you compile or run your code. Keep looking for typos or try compiling/running the same way John did.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with the same type of the files. 
However, I was successful to compile both of the files doing:
cd ..
and compiling from parent folder like this:

> zetcode/*.java

the compilation was successful. But then when i tried

> zetcode>java Snake

Error: Could not find or load main class Snake

The only solution was to go up to two folders, root of the package
and from there issue

> java com.zetcode.Snake

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you pass both files to `javac`, it will look for `skeleton.Board` in a file `skeleton/Board.java` relative to a directory on your source path.

You need to rework the directory structure so that both files are in a directory named "skeleton" which is in the class path, or pass both files as arguments to `javac`.

Comment: I'm passing javac on both files already and java on skeleton.Skeleton

Comment: @Allen, if you run `javac` with `-verbose`, it should print lines like `[search path for source files: ...]
[search path for class files: ...]`.  Is the directory containing the `skeleton` directory on either one of those lists?

Comment: I have updated the question which by useing your solution fixed one problem but another still persists.